# In garbha upanishad, in what way the seven types of colors were classified? And what are the significant of it?

Tags: upanishads

In garbha upanishad it says,

> the colors are basically of seven types viz., white, red, black, smoky gray, yellow and golden white.”

What are these seven types? How these are categories in 7 types?